# What is acTable as a AcDataTransferType after DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Tags: vba, ms-access

First day at a job and I had to took someones code over and in one of the first functions I have this :

```
If ExistTable("S_NEW") Then DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "S_NEW"
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "S_NEW", _
      tmpPATH & Dir(tmpPATH & "S2_*.xlsm "), True, "DF_GRID_1"
DoEvents
  
If ExistTable("FCT_NEW") Then DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "FCT_NEW"
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acTable, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "FCT_NEW", _
      tmpPATH & Dir(tmpPATH & "Fct*.xlsx "), True
DoEvents
```

The first 'if' looks normal, we delete a table and import new data from an excel. But the second 'if' has an acTable as AcDataTransferType which is following the documentation not a choice.. Keep in mind that this person wrote this part of code a very long time ago.

Is it just a simple import ?

Comment: If you right mouse click on `acTable` and ask for the "Definition", does it bring you anywhere or link to anything?

Comment: Does code run without error? It may be an older, undocumented argument.

Answer (score 2):

That's a plain old mistype.

The first argument to `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is a [`AcDataTransferType` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acdatatransfertype), while `acTable` is an [`AcObjectType` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acobjecttype)

`acTable` corresponds to 0, and `acImport` corresponds to 0, so it functions as if it was `acImport`. That means there are no functional consequences.

Comment: He used it on multiple occasions so I dont think it was a mistype but it gets the "thing" done so fine by me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is a syntax error, but it still works!!!

The FIRST value or parameter of docmd.Transferspreadsheet is suppose to be one of these 3 choices:

[image]

So that is a syntax mistake. But, the code STILL worked and works, since

from above, the first value is a "1" or "0" or "2"

This:

[image]

But, it is a typo-o in code. And it should be this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "FCT_NEW", _
  tmpPATH & Dir(tmpPATH & "Fct*.xlsx "), True
```

so, the "incorrect" constant of acTable was used, but it still looks to work since

```
acTable is 0
acImport is 0
```